# How to get maximum elements from a list using numpy.isclose()

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I simply want to choose the elements from legal_values that have the same index as the maximum value in q_values. So in the example below the max q_value is 2, which has index 1, therefore the corresponding element in legal actions is 1. If there are more than one maximum values I want all of the indices of the maximum values to be returned.

When I try the code below:

```
legal_actions = [0, 1]
q_values = [1,2]
legal_actions[np.isclose(q_values, np.max(q_values), 1e-8)]
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Comment: `legal_actions` has to be a numpy array, not a list: `legal_actions = np.array([0, 1])`

Comment: Why not just `legal_actions[q == q.max()]` or so? You're dealing with integers after all. Also, convert your lists to arrays.

Comment: @Stef. Argmax won't help if you want all the indices.

Comment: Google your errors please.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: correct, I didn't carefully read the question.